# Creating dojo button declaritively

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to make dojo buttons declaratively rather than programmatically. However, I cannot seem to get the `data-dojo-props iconClass` attribute to work correctly.

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dojoMain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="picForm" name="picForm" action="#">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="hide">   </button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="next" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon'" type="button"></button>
</p>
```

I have dojo.js correctly linked as my first problem was spelling digit rather than dijit... However, now when trying the `data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon'"` it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Just noticed the a lack of closing quotations in the meta tag, however, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you missed to refer a dojo css theme file by example [claro.css](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css) , don't forget to append `class="claro"` to your body tag.

**Second point** is also you missed a class that refer to icon , note that dojo use sprites css , `dijitEditorIcon` refer to image url background and you have to specify a second class that refers to the postion of this last in the images background  `iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut'`

you can find here icon class name for dijitEditorIcon [IconClass names](http://amagard.x10.mx/dojo_icon_classes.html)

bellow a working snippet :

```js
require(["dojo/parser"],function(parser){
  parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
  <p id="picForm" name="picForm" action="#">
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitCheckBoxIcon'" data-dojo-id="hide"> </button>
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="next" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut'" type="button"></button>
  </p>
</body>
```

Refer to this for more understanding about available themes => [Link](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/themes.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm now!